# The articles disappeared

Tags: grammar, articles

The sentence is:

"Volunteers were all over the age of 18, but researchers didn't specify their familiarity with art or their ethnic or national origin."

In the previous sentences we already read about volunteers and researchers
(https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2020/02/do-you-weird-art-blame-your-brain)

Why it is not:

"The volunteers were all over the age of 18, but the researchers didn't specify their familiarity with art or their ethnic or national origin."

Comment: Use of the definite articles here would be quite proper, but dropping them is quite acceptable; here, it's more 'clinical-ese' (ie gives a professional, official feel) than headlinese (sounding like a tabloid headline).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Thank you!